# Orbit of conjugation on subgroups of $D_8$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, dihedral-groups

Let $X$ be the *set* of all subgroups of $D_8$ with order $2$. For fixed $g\in D_8$, and for all $x\in X$, conjugation by $g$ is defined by
$$x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$$
What is the orbit of this group action? I have that $X=\{\{e,r^2\},\{e,s\},\{e,sr\},\{e,r^2s\},\{e,rs\}\}$

Comment: One remark: It would be better to call $X$ the *set* of all subgroups ..., as opposed to the *group* of all subgroups - $X$ really doesn't have a natural group structure.

Comment: Firstly, $X$ is not a group, it is a set. Secondly, orbit is for an element of the set $X$.

Comment: Is this not a subgroup?

Comment: @JB071098 as jpvee pointed, $X$ does not have a group structure.

Comment: I see. I edited this.

Comment: So for which element of $X$ are you finding the orbit?

Comment: So $D_8$ acts on $X$ by conjugation. I just want to know how to find the orbit of an element of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orbit is that of an element of the set $X$ on which the group is acting. For example,
$$\text{Orb}(\{e,r^2\})=g\{e,r^2\}g^{-1}=\{e,gr^2g^{-1}\}.$$
The second element $gr^2g^{-1}$ will run over all conjugates of $r^2$, thus you need the conjugacy class of $r^2$, which is just....... Can you take it from here?

**Added explanation:**
Either $g=r^k$ or $g=sr^k$, with $k \in\{0,1,2,3\}$. Thus, if $g=r^k$, then the only conjugate we get is $r^kr^2r^{-k}=r^2$.

With $g=sr^k$, we get $(sr^k)r^2(sr^k)^{-1}=sr^{2}s=r^{-2}=r^2$.

So only conjugate of $r^2$ is $r^2$. This means 
$$\text{Orb}(\{e,r^2\})=\{\{e,r^2\}\}.$$

Comment: Can we say anything about the order of the element $gr^2g^{-1}$?

Comment: @JB071098 conjugates have same order, so you are only working with order $2$ elements.

Comment: @JB071098 I have added more explanation.

Comment: Is this true for each element of $X$?

Comment: @JB071098 you have to use the same idea for each element. But if you are thinking that the orbit for each element in $X$ will turn out to be the set containing only that element (as it happened in my example), then that is not true. For example conjugates of $s$ are $s,sr^2$, so the orbit of $\{e,s\}$ will have both $\{e,s\}$ and $\{e,sr^2\}$.